# Display all history records for an Asset on View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an MVC/EF Code-First application. As one last feature, I'm adding a history table `INV_AssetsHistory` which will have a record each time a record is `Insert/Update` in `INV_Assets`. What I'm trying to figure out now is how to display each of the `INV_AssetsHistory` records for a particular Asset on my View -- say the user selects a particular asset for `Edit/Delete`, I want them to see each record in `INV_AssetsHistory` for this particular `INV_Assets` on the View.

Can anyone provide an example of how to go about this? Based on my experience with MVC, I'm thinking I need to add a foreign key property somewhere between the 2 tables, and then have an `ICollection<>` property to hold all of the `INV_AssetsHistory` records, but I'm not sure of the syntax to implement this functionality.

**Update:**

I tried the following:

- Added to `INV_Assets`:

  ```
  public virtual ICollection<INV_AssetsHistory> AssetHistoryRecords { get; set; }`
  ```
- Changed on `INV_AssetsHistory`

  ```
  public int AssetId { get; set; }
  ```

  to

  ```
  public virtual INV_Assets INV_Asset { get; set; }
  ```
- Created a new `Migration`, and ran `update-database`.

This resulted in:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.INV_AssetsHistory_dbo.INV_Assets_INV_Asset_Id' on table 'INV_AssetsHistory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

**Update 2:**

**INV_Assets**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets 
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**INV_AssetsHistory**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    public class INV_AssetsHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AssetId { get; set; }

        //public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        //public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove all unrelated code including the commented.

Comment: There's an abundance of questions about this "cycles or multiple cascade paths" message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an asset record has an id in SQL, you could create a method that retrieves the asset history from the history table by using the asset id. Something like this perhaps.

Just pass in the assetId as the parameter.

**In your Data Repository**

```
public IQueryable<INV_AssetsHistory> GetHistoryByAssetId(int assetId)
{
  var records = _dataContext.INV_AssetsHistory.Where
   (
      x => x.AssetId == assetId
   );
   return records;
}
```

**In Your Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewAsset(int id = 0)
    {
        // Add Asset History to the View
        ViewBag.History = _repository.GetHistoryByAssetId(id)

        // Asset Details
        var asset = _assetRepository.GetAssetById(id);
        return View("AssetDetails", asset);
    }
```

**In Your View**

```
<tbody>
  @foreach (var action in ViewBag.History)
  {
    <tr>
       <td>@action.something</td>
    </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

Feel free to correct me if I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I probably should have included my Model definitions in the beginning. I've added them above in my EDIT2. My default design idea for the `INV_AssetsHistory` table was to have it contain the exact same fields/definitions with the only difference being an `AssetId` field to designate which Asset is regarded in the history record.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic If you are referencing the asset by AssetId in your INV_AssetsHistory table then this method should work. In your controller, you could call this method; using the assetId as your parameter, and then pass the returned IQueryable list to your view.

Comment: Currently I'm not directly referencing as the 2 tables are not actually linked at the moment (do they need to be?) I think this could really work for what I'm after. Any suggestions for how to call/use this from my View? I think I just want to display a small table and `foreach` through the returned `records` variable.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic well, you could just create another action in your controller to handle the Asset History part. In your inventory list, generate a hyperlink for each asset and then link to the AssetHistory action, using the assetID as a parameter. 
In the AssetHistory action method, accept the assetId and then call the above method in your data repository. Otherwise, you could just use the above code right in your controller. The tables don't necessarily have to be linked for this to work.

Comment: In my "Inventory List"? I was ideally wanting to get all the `AssetHistory` records for an `Asset` and display them in a grid/table on the View when a user goes to `Edit/DeleteConfirm` an Asset.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic My apologies. I was thinking to much along the lines of an application I had written myself. For this, you could use a ViewBag to pass the Asset history to the same view. `ViewBag.History = _repository.GetHistoryByAssetId(assetId)` and then enumerate over the viewbag in your view.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good idea. Do you have any simple examples of iterating through the Viewbag in the View?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic I updated my answer with an attempt to demonstrate this for you. Basically, the ViewBag will represent the list of events for an asset's history so you just want to loop over each event and create a new row and within that row, table data for each member

Comment: Interesting. It seems your driving more towards a link to display the `AssetHistory` record on a seperate View, whereas I was attempting to show the `AssetHistory` for the individual `Asset` right there on the `Asset` view in a kind of scrollable table/div.

Comment: You could still put it in the same view with the ViewBag. Just Grab the Asset ID from your model and pass that into the method. I just have a habit of doing it this way because I like using popup modal windows and binding to the view with JSON